# No such property error for class

Tags: grails

I am getting the following error:

> No such property: activity for class: com.moog.Project

project.groovy

```
package com

class Project {

    String project
    Workpackage workpackage

    static hasMany=[workpackage:Workpackage]


    static constraints = {
        project  blank:false
        workpackage  blank:false
        workpackage nullable:true
        project nullable:true
    }
    static mapping=
    {


    }
}
```

workpackage.groovy

```
package com

class Workpackage {

    String workpackage
    static belongsTo=[project:Project]
    Activity activity
    static hasMany=[activity:Activity]
    static constraints = {
        workpackage blank:false
        workpackage nullable:true
        project nullable:true
        workpackage(inList: ['pcn', 'sct'])


    }
    static mapping={


    }

}
```

activity.goovy

```
package com

class Activity {
    String activity

    static belongsTo=[workpackage:Workpackage]

    static constraints = {
        activity blank:false,unique:true,nullable:true
        workpackage nullable:true
        activity(inList:['excellent','good','average','bad'])
    }
}
```

Comment: No such property: activity for class: com.moog.Project

Answer (score 1):

First, the code in your question puts `Project` in the `com` package, not `com.moog`.

Aside from that, there literally is no property in your `Project` class called `activity`. You declare `project` and `workproduct` and nothing else. That's exactly what the error message says.

Comment: how to combine project vs workpackage and workpackage vs activity.if we are using three domain classes

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. Do you have [another question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)